# Jquery Ajax success method being called too early?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a series of knockout components that perform several ajax calls back to the server to fetch data. Many of these components inherit the same javascript base-class. During testing I've noticed that occasionally these ajax calls appear to grab incorrect data.

I set a breakpoint within my browser console inside the `$.ajax` success method, and I've noticed that sometimes this success method fires even before the network tab has said that the call has finished returning data. When I look at the data that's being returned, it gives me the source for the current page, not the queried url. This page performs 40-50 ajax calls at a time, but each control handles its own loading.

This appears to happen at complete random, and if I put the same control on the page multiple times, often several will load successfully, and others will not. Here's what I have:

```
this.Update = function () {
        this.updateParameters();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            traditional: true,
            url: this.ajax_location,
            data: this.ajax_parameters,
            success: function (data) {
                this.seriesDataItems = new Array();
                var that = this;
                if (data.MonthlyTotals) {
                    data.MonthlyTotals.forEach(function (e, i, a) {
                        that.seriesDataItems.push([e.Item1, (+e.Item2.toFixed(2))]);  // stupid Tuple serialization...
                    });
                }
                if (data.Total) this.visitCount(this.magicRegex(+data.Total.toFixed(2)));
                this.posNeg(data.PercentYTD > 0 ? "fa fa-arrow-circle-down" : "fa fa-arrow-circle-up");
                this.percentage(Math.round(Math.abs(data.PercentYTD * 100)) + "%");
                this.seriesData(this.seriesDataItems);
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (returndata) {
                alert("Error:\n" + returndata.responseText);
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: 40-50 AJAX calls per page sounds incredibly excessive. Are you sure your server is handling all those without errors? Have you disabled caching on the AJAX request?

Comment: Unfortunately it's the design decision management wishes to use. The page is a dashboard with approximately 30 widgets. Each widget can have several smaller components included. They wish for each widget to be entirely self contained and reusable so that it makes all of its own ajax calls. There's very minimal overlap between what the calls query, so changing the design paradigm would still require a fairly large viewmodel.

Comment: Also, I have yet to disable caching on the ajax calls, but the data seems to be accurate on each page load (when it actually waits for the request to complete before calling the success handler).

Comment: I don't know for sure but maybe there is a limitation somewhere which limits the amount of Ajax requests you can execute at the same time. You might want to consider queuing those Ajax requests.

Comment: an obvious question, but does this "corruption" happen in all browsers, have you tested other browsers?

Comment: I've only been testing in chrome for the time being. But I've noticed that if I throw an if block around the `#this.percentage()` portion, the error doesn't occur. I'm thinking it may be some sort of ajax race condition where it's just getting triggered prematurely, and it gets triggered again when the data actually loads. Sometimes the data loads before initialization, sometimes after.

Comment: what does `this.percentage` function look like - maybe you have an inadvertent global variable (jshint/jslint your code)

Comment: It's actually a knockout bound observable. I'm just updating the knockout observable within that function.

Comment: I have a multi queue thing I wrote a year back - it's a bit rough (and it's ES5 not ES2015+ ), never used in production - but what it does is allow you to add a bunch of promises and it makes sure only a maximum set amount are concurrent, as $.ajax returns a Promise, it could be used, not sure - the code in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dmmp0bs/1/) has a default maximum 4 concurrency, you can always tweak the code - from something I read I think that's the maximum Chrome will allow anyway! try the code, see if it helps, no guarantees, if it reprograms your VCR, I apologise in advance :p